# pandas dataframe group by values of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

| id | expNumber | attempt | finished | successful |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | true | false |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | false | false |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | true | true |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | false | false |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | true | false |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | true | true |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | false | false |
| 1 | 4 | 2 | false | false |

```
id,expNumber,attempt,finished,successful,
1,1,1,true,false,
1,1,2,false,false,
1,1,3,true,true,
1,2,1,false,false,
1,2,2,true,false,
1,2,3,true,true,
1,4,1,false,false,
1,4,2,false,false,
```

And I want to create a dataframe which counts the data grouped by the value of the column. Here is what I expect:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| true | 4 |
| false | 4 |

I tried the following code but when I print the result, its just empty.

```
df = df.groupby('finished'.sum())
print("test", df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select columns for count and use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df[['finished','successful']].apply(pd.value_counts)
print("test", df)
test        finished  successful
False         4           6
True          4           2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of the following:

```
df.groupby("finished").count()
```

Or:

```
df["finished"].value_counts()
```